# Use specific screensaver when Remoting into another desktop

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, remote-desktop, screensaver

My company has PCs (Windows 7 & 10) in our lab that are used by clinicians. As software engineers, we sometimes remote into these computers to get logs or debug issues. When we do, it kicks off the current user if there is one, and shows the screen saver. I am wondering if it is possible to show a specific screen saver like ("SOMEONE IS REMOTED IN... DO NOT TURN OFF") or something when remoting in...

Thanks.

Comment: The "screensaver" is a moving background that activates after a defined period of inactivity. What shows when someone is logged in via RDP is the lock screen image. This is an interesting question. A quick Google search doesn't appear to show there are any current tools to accomplish this.